# Proof feedback: integral of a function with f(x)=0 is 0

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm attempting to prove the following statement, and having some difficulty:

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ and $\alpha(x)=x$.

Prove: If $\int_a^b f \, d\alpha=0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

My attempt, seeking to find a contradiction, goes as follows:

Assume $\int_a^b f \,d\alpha=0$ and $f(c)=q>0$ for some $c \in [a,b].$

$Lemma \ 1:$ Let $f$ be continuous at $c$ and suppose $f(c)\neq 0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ and an interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ in which $f$ has the same sign as $f(c)$.

Since $f(c)=q>0$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, we invoke $Lemma \ 1$ and get that there exists $x$ such that $f(x)>\frac{f(c)}{2}=\frac{q}{2}$ when $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Now, note that for any partition $P$, we have $U(P,f,\alpha)>\delta\frac{q}{2}>0$, since we would always at least have $f(x)$ in some arbitrarily small $\delta$-interval. We then get that
$$
    0<\frac{q}{2} \delta \leq \overline{\int_a^b} f \, d\alpha = \int_a^b f \, d\alpha=0
$$
which is a contradiction. So $f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in[a,b]$.

In general, I feel ok about this proof, but there are certainly some gaps that I can't seem to entirely justify. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use "align" in MathJax in a display that has only one line and no alignment tabs?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm brand new to TeX, any recommendations on how to improve my typesetting is appreciated. Frankly this was copy and pasted from Overleaf in the interest of time.

Comment: This looks very close to spot on although I wonder if you might want to relate the integral to a lower sum. There may be upper sums whose values exceed the value of the integral. And the last equation does seem that it relates somehow to lower sums.

Comment: @leslietownes thanks for the feedback. It crossed my mind to do this, given it might clarify the inequalities at the end. I guess the lower integral would then clearly be greater than q/2*delta, given it would be the supremum of all the lower sums. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It depends upon how the integral is defined. Often $f$ is said to be Riemann integrable if an infimum of a set of "upper sums" (suitably defined) coincides with a supremum of a set of "lower sums" (suitably defined), so that $\int f \geq L$ is guaranteed when $L$ is any particular lower sum. That's what I was thinking about.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd I personally think this is a good proof, except that $U$ should be replaced by $L$. Indeed, it is the lower sums that converge to the lower RS integral.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon oops! I totally overlooked that. In my original proof I tried to use the lower sums, and forgot to change the lower integal to the upper integral.Thanks

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd Now it is good!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon great. Could this also be more simply done using the following logic: Let g(x)=0. Since f is positive somewhere, we know that f >= g, which implies that the integral of f is >= the integral of g, which is 0. So we have that \int f >= 0, but the integral is equal to zero by assumption.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd We have that $\int f \geq 0$ but $\int f  = 0$ by assumption. Now how would you get $f =0$ from here? I think this leads to the same proof as you have given , which is to assume that $f >0$ on one point, which by continuity leads to it being positive on a bigger part and so on.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon good point. I'm mostly just looking to clarify that last leap, namely the statement, "Now, note that for any partition P, we have U(P,f,α)>δq/2>0, since we would always at least have f(x) in some arbitrarily small δ-interval." I doubt I will get full credit for such a leap.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd You are not far away from full credit. I'd assume if you wrote out just one more expression i.e. the definition of $U(P,f,\alpha)$ then you can easily make the bound clear. Another thing : it is $U(P,f,\alpha) \geq \frac{\delta q}{2} > 0$ , note the $\geq$. Small error, but I thought I should point it out. If I were instructor and this were my course, you'd be getting full credit for sure , then again not every instructor is lenient!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon if $f(c)>\frac{q}{2}$, would it be possible that $U(P,f,\alpha)=\delta \frac{q}{2}$? I figured it must be strictly greater.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd Oh, I did not see the $>$ sign there! Sorry. Of course you'd have $>$ then.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd We can look to answer this question and close it, since the matter has been resolved. Either you can answer it , by mentioning a summary of our comments here, or I can do the same. Take your pick, but if you do decide to answer the question then call me once you are done from the comments section. Accept the answer which comes , when you can do so. I have given you a +1 for your interest in the conversation and your attempt at writing a good question. Very impressed, your question deserves the attention it got.